# how to set volume of remote machine to the maximum level

Tags: c#, powershell, audio, volume

I am developing a feature in my application where I want a target machine on my network (not the machine I am running the app from) to play the "tada" noise. 
The target computer's name is other-Machine-name.
I am able to get "tada" to play by using the following code, but the sound cannot be heard if other-Machine-name's audio setting is on mute or too low.

```
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/k C:\\PSTools\\psexec -accepteula -h -d \\\\other-Machine-name powershell -c (New-Object Media.SoundPlayer \"C:\\Windows\\Media\\tada.wav\").PlaySync()");
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            Process p = Process.Start(info);
```

Edit: The use case for this app is to identify online machines in my lab by using sound. I want to know where other-Machine-name is at by playing the sound only, and not by going to each machine to install an agent or script

How can I have my code adjust the volume to the maximum level on the remote machine? I'm assuming that setting it to the maximum level will override "mute" if it is on? I am currently using a combination of psexec and powertools to play "tada" (this might not be the best way to do it, but it works.) I do not necessarily need to use powertools to adjust the volume (if there is a way, please advise) I'm just looking for any bit of code that will work for this.

Comment: Do you have physical access to the machine in question?

Comment: Yes, I have physical access.

Comment: Then you do it like [this](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Set-PC-Volume-1737b160).  I don't have to tell you the many reasons this is a bad idea, do I?

Comment: One of the comments mentions that it doesn't work on version's later than XP. The target systems where I am adjusting the volume are all Windows 7 and Windows 8. And even though I have physical access to the machines, I do not want to go around to each one of them physically for a reason I will explain by editing my original OP.

Comment: http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-7/122140-change-volume-remote-pc.html Is Google down today?